# Using IP 127.0.0.1 for network communication

Tags: java, swing, networking

I have created a list of my friends' names. By clicking on their names one frame should get opened for me and a second one on the machine where the friend has the same application running.Just like the chat window in a messenger application. I use the IP address 127.0.0.1 fort this. Will this wor?

this is my list action performed:

```
private void jList1ValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {                                    

    ChatFrame frame = new ChatFrame(client);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is an IP Address, not a port. What do you mean by one for me, one for them? Is the second frame supposed to show on a different machine? Or on the same, but with different information in it? For the actual question: You should know if this is the correct behaviour or not. And you also should be able to test, if it works or not.

Comment: like chat frame.when you click on the name of your friends suddenly one chat frame will be shown for you and the other chat frame will be shown for your friend in the other machine .but I use 127.0.0.1 IP address and shows both chat frames for me.is this correct? I mean that in the jList1valueChanged I want to show one frame but it will show 2 frames,is this correct??

Comment: Ok, I hope the question text now reflects your actual question. If this is the case, I suggest you do some reading on network basics (with Java), for example: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, let me see if I got this straight: you're creating something akin to an IM, right?

And you're using a connection on a port at `127.0.0.1`?

As we all know the `127.0.0.1` is a [loopback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) address, it will only point to one's machine. No matter what machine.

**IF** you're trying to create an IM, you need a server to handle the messages, **OR** know the remote address you're trying to connect (and a server there could be made to provide such address, that's how Yahoo Messenger does).